# Generic flags for a model in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, architecture

I am making a Ruby on Rails app and am realizing that my User class could potentially end up with a lot of generic boolean / integer attributes.  For example, suppose I have a promotion each quarter, and I only want a person to be able to use the promotion once.  Then I'd have to make a new column each quarter has_used_promotion_N to track that promotion.

Alternatively, I'm thinking of creating a new column called "Generic Flags" which is just a comma separated value of flags set on the account.  For example:

"has_used_promotion_1, has_used_promotion_2, limit_on_feature_a=20" etc. could be set for some particular user

(or maybe I'll store it as JSON)

In any case, I'm thinking of giving myself some sort of NoSQL-like functionality in my DB.

Is this really bad design for some reason?  Has anyone else done this before?  Anything I'm completely missing about RoR?

Comment: Be wary of implementing a database inside your database. You will create more work for yourself than you will need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion Promotion should be a separate model with a many to many relationship with User. When you have a promotion you would create a Promotion instance and when a person uses that promotion you add that person to promotion.users relationship.

This is much better than your idea because you can now query those relationship. Want a list of all users that used the first quarter promotion? No problem. You can do that with your solution, but you have to resort to some hackiness (is that a word?) to do it, and you'd have to parse the generic flag string for EVERY user on EVERY query. Not ideal to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an arbitrarily-sized collection of associations then it should be a real relation, modeled using the existing DB and facilities. Promotions sounds like that, and it seems like it would be something you'd be modeling in your DB already; no real reason to keep a duplicate value hierarchy.

For *actually*-generic flags, you could have a named-flag table and again use a real association.

You `could` also just serialize a flag object to a text column. Doing so impedes your ability to do trivial searches on a flag/flag value, however. This may not matter for a wad of flags associated with a single user that you don't care about unless they're logged in, but tread lightly--it depends on your usecase.